# Change color using oncopy and onpaste

Tags: javascript, html

I want to use a `contentededitable` and use the `oncopy` and `onpaste` functions to change the color of text. When text is copied from the `contentedittable` I want the text to be red, if it's pasted then I want to change the text color to green. Is this achievable and how can I do it?

HTML:

```
<html>

  <head>
    <audio id="copy" src="https://www.soundjay.com/button/sounds/beep-21.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
    <audio id="paste" src="https://www.soundjay.com/button/sounds/beep-22.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <button onclick="playCopy()">Copy Sound</button>
    <button onclick="playPaste()">Paste Sound</button>
    <p>Enter text here and copy</p>
    <span id="content"  oncopy="copy()" onpaste="paste()" contenteditable>Test words to copy and paste</span>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p>This is the text in the clipboard</p>
    <textarea id="clipBoard" readonly></textarea>
  </body>

</html>

<script>
function playCopy() {
    document.getElementById('copy').play();
}
function playPaste() {
    document.getElementById('paste').play();
}
function copy(){

}

function paste(){

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the best code but I hope it gives you a bit kick start and gets you going. Also can have bit issue with pasting color as when the content get pasted the function `paste()` gets executed first and then the content is pasted. I Will edit this answer once I get a better solution.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <audio id="copy" src="https://www.soundjay.com/button/sounds/beep-21.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
  <audio id="paste" src="https://www.soundjay.com/button/sounds/beep-22.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    .color-red {
      color: red;
    }

    .color-green {
      color: green;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="playCopy()">Copy Sound</button>
  <button onclick="playPaste()">Paste Sound</button>
  <p>Enter text here and copy</p>
  <span id="content" oncopy="copy()" onpaste="paste()" contenteditable>Test words to copy and paste</span>
  <br>
  <br>
  <p>This is the text in the clipboard</p>
  <textarea id="clipBoard" readonly></textarea>
</body>

</html>

<script>
  function playCopy() {
    document.getElementById('copy').play();
  }

  function playPaste() {
    document.getElementById('paste').play();
  }

  function copy() {
    document.getElementById('content').classList.remove('color-green');
    document.getElementById('content').classList.add('color-red');
  }

  function paste() {
    document.getElementById('content').classList.remove('color-red');
    document.getElementById('content').classList.add('color-green');
  }
</script>
```